# boost::lexical_cast compiles with warnings

Tags: c++, boost, warnings, iso, lexical-cast

Compiling the following:

```
// file main.cpp

#include <string>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( 656.16 );
    return 0;
}
```

yields to this:

```
/usr/local/include/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:1184: warning: ISO C++ does not support the ‘%lg’ printf format
```

Why? How to avoid this warning?

Comment: Write a patch, send it to boost mailinglist. They usually dont care much about warnings. I have written myself a wrapperscript around gcc that filters out all the boost warnings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I GCC, there’s a simple trick to silence all warnings from a specific library’s headers. Simply treat them as *system* headers. This is safe, as far as I know, and I use it as a course of standard practice.

That is, tweak your command line to use `-isystem` instead of `-I` to specify the Boost header location. Everything else stays the same.

For instance, this is taken from a `Makefile` of one of my projects:

```
BOOST=/usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.48.0
CXXFLAGS+=-isystem$(BOOST)
```

Note: it is important that you **don’t silence warnings** in general in your projects. On the contrary, you should treat all warnings as errors (`-Werror`) and warn as much as possible (.e.g. `-Wall -Wextra`). The above disables only those warnings caused by Boost, not from your own code. This is as it should be.